# Type deduction fails for array of enum interface

Tags: kotlin, interface, casting, type-inference, type-deduction

In the following minimal example `useFoos(a)` is totally fine, but `useFoos(b)` gives a [compiler error](https://pl.kotl.in/giVZShSta).

```kotlin
interface FooInterface

fun useFoos(foos: Array<FooInterface>) {}

enum class FooEnum : FooInterface

fun main() {
    val a = FooEnum.values()
    useFoos(a as Array<FooInterface>)
    useFoos(a)

    val b = FooEnum.values()
    useFoos(b) // Error: Type mismatch: inferred type is Array<FooEnum> but Array<FooInterface> was expected
    useFoos(b as Array<FooInterface>)
}
```

And idea why this is? And if it's not a compiler bug, but intended behavior instead, could somebody point me to the place where this behavior is specified/explained?

Comment: [smart-casts](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/typecasts.html#smart-casts)

Comment: Probably because if the check succeed at the time of casting then compiler already knows that the next time we'll send that value there will be no probelms. If you use `as?` instead of `as` then the smart cast is impossible since you didn't got exception that is thrown out and in next line there might be a type-mismatch occur.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained by @IR42 in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61774428/type-deduction-fails-for-array-of-enum-interface#comment109266368_61774428), it's because of [smart casts](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/typecasts.html#smart-casts).

Using the [`out` keyword](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#declaration-site-variance) helps to make it work without casting.

Corrected code:

```kotlin
interface FooInterface

fun useFoos(foos: Array<out FooInterface>) {}

enum class FooEnum : FooInterface

fun main() {
    val a = FooEnum.values()
    useFoos(a as Array<FooInterface>)
    useFoos(a)

    val b = FooEnum.values()
    useFoos(b)
    useFoos(b as Array<FooInterface>)
}
```